# Delphi multiple .ini files operation

Tags: delphi, ini

Recently, I encountered a little issue, which causes an access violation when trying to read .ini files.

My question is, can I load multiple .ini files (e.g. settings.ini and data.ini) within one and the same procedure? For instance, I have two ini files, which I write in and read from.

Here is a shortened proc, which writes data:

```
//writing to file uninstall.ini
try
  ini := TIniFile.Create(edPath.Text + '\Uninstall.ini');
  ini.WriteString('Uninstall', 'qfProgramName', Label4.Caption);
  ini.WriteString('Uninstall', 'qfUninstPath', edPath.Text);
finally
  ini.Free;
end;
```

And then, there is this this code (in the same procedure)

```
configini := configini.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\quickfix.ini');
sectionsCount := getMaxSectionIndex(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\quickfix.ini');

startmenuLoc := GetProperDir(_STARTMENU);
desktopLoc := GetProperDir(_DESKTOP);
for I := 1 to sectionsCount do begin
  currentSection := 'qfShortcut_' + IntToStr(I);
  shortcutFile := configini.ReadString(currentSection, 'qfShTarget', '');
  shortcutDesc := configini.ReadString(currentSection, 'qfShDescription', '');
  shortcutFullPath := installPath + '\' + shortcutFile;
  shortcutDest := configini.ReadString(currentSection, 'qfShPath', '');
  displayName := configini.ReadString(currentSection, 'qfDisplayName', '');

  showmessage(startmenuLoc + '\' + displayName + '.lnk');
  showmessage(shortcutFullPath);

  if shortcutDest = 'spStartMenu' then CreateLink(shortcutFullPath, startmenuLoc + '\' + displayName + '.lnk', '', '');
  if shortcutDest = 'spDesktop' then CreateLink(shortcutFullPath, desktopLoc + '\' + displayName + '.lnk', '', '');
```

The line with the second loaded file crashes with the access violation. It's not excluded, that the trouble comes from some other location, however, I would like you guys to take a look, maybe someone will see another problem.

This snippet is to create shortcuts on the desktop and in start menu, loading data from .ini files. File "quickfix.ini" is also loaded once at OnCreate, but freed then.

Comment: On which line does the access violation occur?

Comment: Your `try` is incorrect. Goes like this: `obj := TObject.Create; try dostuff; finally obj.Free; end;` Please take this opportunity to learn how to debug. It is much more efficient to be able to perform basic debugging yourself. Having to ask Stack Overflow questions every time you make a little mistake (which we all do a lot) is not efficient. If you were able to debug then you'd know which line of code raised the access violation and you'd understand what was wrong. On the other hand, perhaps you don't yet know what an access violation actually is. That knowledge is essential.

Comment: Keith, access violation occurs on line where I load the quickfix.ini, however, even when I comment out all the other surrounding code, access violation still persists. David, thanks for answer, however, I recoded my try statements and nothing has changed. Any other ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't say that the try was the problem. That was just some free advice. I still don't know which line the error occurred on. And you'd still be able to solve this with some debugging. Have you ever done any debugging before, or do you always try to solve problems by reading the code? Do you know what an access violation is? Don't take this the wrong way, I'm trying to lead you to new skills that will make you a better programmer.

Comment: Thanks, David, I understand your point, I know what an access violation is, but yet I really have no clue about how to debug it, or how to trace out the correct line of malicious code. The only thing I know is, that this exception comes out with ini.create(quickfix), because when I comment it out, it never happens again...note: my access violation is reading at 00000004

Comment: Solved. Thanks, David, now I should take a closer look at debugging :)

Comment: Turns out I was blind!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try replacing

```
configini := configini.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\quickfix.ini');
```

with:

```
configini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\quickfix.ini');
```

You are trying to call Create on an uninitialized variable rather than on a class.

Comment: Keith. I owe you a beer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, that's it, amazed we didn't spot it, we've seen it so many times before!! Well done.